# Partial and named arguments in Clojure

Tags: python, clojure, functional-programming, partial, higher-order-functions

I'm a Python programmer just learning Clojure.  In Python I love how I can used named arguments in a call to functools.partial:

```
def pow(base, exponent):
    return base ** exponent

exp = partial(pow, 2.71828)           # exp(2) --> 7.3886
square = partial(pow, exponent=2)     # square(2) --> 4
```

The implementation of `exp` is is obviously equivalent in Clojure - but could I use `partial` to define `square` succinctly, too?  Is there a way to pass in keyword/named arguments to partial so that a specific argument is pre-determined?  Or would this have to be handled not by `partial` but a function literal, e.g. `#(pow % 2)`?

Comment: Short answer: This isn't idiomatic. Clojure's preference for dispatch by argument count is related to what the JVM can implement efficiently (destructuring is considerably more expensive in comparison); the further you get from that, the more your code suffers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For existing functions you will need to use function literal because they are not using keyword based arguments and use positional arguments.

For your own function you can do something similar:

```
(defn my-pow [& {:keys [base exponent]}]
  (Math/pow base exponent))

(def exp (partial my-pow :base 2.71828))
(exp :exponent 2)
(def square (partial my-pow :exponent 2))
(square :base 2)
```

Comment: Thanks.  But now I *must* use the keyword in the function call, don't I?  `(exp 2)` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Thats why I said "something similar" ;)